# Tanuki Wrapper debug works for a while, then it errors with "Out of memory in logging code (P3)"

Tags: java, tomcat, java-8, sap-commerce-cloud, tanuki

I'm debugging an old Hybris application.
I can build it and I can serve it without any problems.
I've always seen problems when I try to serve it in debug mode.
I was able to serve it in **debug mode** basically all day yesterday.
Today it stopped working again.
I suspect it has something to do with Java or JVM (since I've been playing with SDK MAN, so I've been switching between 2 JDK 8 versions).

Now I'm using the Zulu 1.8 392 and I'm about to switch back to Oracle.
Just want to do a fresh boot of the Mac (Macbook Pro M3 pro with 36GB).

Tanuki Wrapper is at v 3.5.29 (I found out that there was a memory leak before 3.5.28)

Keep posted here if it solves.

But what I'm looking for is basically understand if maybe some log file becomes too large (and then causes the failure) or basically if restarting the JVM could be enough.

For now I'm quite sure it's not the tomcat options, since it's configured with
`-Xmx10G -Xms5G` (and again because it worked long enough).

**EDIT**

Still no joy with reboot and switching to Oracle.

**RE-EDIT**

Tried this, but not doing anything

```
wrapper.filter.trigger.1=java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
wrapper.filter.action.1=RESTART
```

Comment: The two geniuses who voted for closing could at least tell why

Comment: without any code to show ([mcve]), there's not much help anyone could provide debugging - maybe other than "use a profiler". As it is, due to the lack of code, this question is not quite programming-related

Comment: Ok, but it's directly related to programming. I was figuring that people using that Hybris, may be here on StackOverflow and maybe faced the same issue.
Maybe I should post somewhere else, like serverfault. I will do.